# Running multiple queries inside one cfquery code block

Tags: sql-server-2008, coldfusion, coldfusion-9

DB: MSSQL 2008
CF Version: 9

```
<cfquery name="rsData" datasource="#request.dsn#">
SELECT GETDATE() AS CurrentDateTime1
SELECT GETDATE() AS CurrentDateTime2
</cfquery>
<cfoutput query="rsData">  
    #rsData.CurrentDateTime1#
    #rsData.CurrentDateTime2#
</cfoutput>
<cfdump var="#rsData#">
```

I would expect to be able to output #rsData.CurrentDateTime2# as this is written but I get a hard error:

```
Element CURRENTDATETIME2 is undefined in rsData
```

Any ideas as to why? Is there a CFAdmin setting that needs to be enabled? There are other areas of the code where this works just fine so I'm a bit perplexed. Any suggestions on where to look to resolve this would be appreciated.

** UPDATED BASED UPON LEIGH'S ANSWER MAKING ME GO BACK AND SEE MY TYPO **
This is just a dirty example of what I was ultimately trying to do and may not work.

```
declare @start  DATETIME, @end DATETIME
    set @start = (
        select max(date) DTM
        from TABLE)
        SET @lowStart_Search = dateadd(year,-1,@highStart_Search)

        SELECT COLUMN1, COLUMN2  
        WHERE column3 <= @start  
        AND   column3 >= @end
```

Comment: This article about setting "allowMultiQueries=true" in the admin might be relevant to your situation but I've never actually used it. http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1209-turning-on-multiple-statements-in-coldfusion-8-mysql-4-5-datasource.htm

Comment: Why do you need multiple queries to run this? Why not just `SELECT getDate() AS date1, getDate() AS date2`

Comment: @tonyjunkes - from my research, that only applies to MySQL unless you know otherwise.

Comment: @MattBusche the getDate() were just examples of a select statement. In the code, they are performing lookups.

Comment: to others reading this, the question above has been updated to include resemblance of the corrected code. The issue was I had two selects instead of a **SET** and a **SELECT**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> There are other areas of the code where this works just fine

That seems unlikely. There must be something different about the other queries.

It is not about multiple SQL statements per se, but how many resultsets those statements generate. `CFQuery` is only capable of returning a *single* [resultset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Result_set). The SQL above generates multiple resultsets:

- Resultset 1: `SELECT GETDATE() AS CurrentDateTime1`
- Resultset 2: `SELECT GETDATE() AS CurrentDateTime2`

Notice if you run it in SSMS it produces two result grids, not one?

**First Result**

```
CurrentDateTime1
------------------
October, 05 2015 16:36:31
(1 row affected)
```

**Second Result**

```
CurrentDateTime2
------------------
October, 05 2015 16:36:31
(1 row affected)
```

The CFQuery tag will only return the first result. The rest will be ignored. Hence why `CurrentDateTime2` is undefined.

You can certainly modify the SQL to return both values, if needed. For example, return them as two separate *columns* of a single resultset.

```
 SELECT GETDATE() AS CurrentDateTime1
      , GETDATE() AS CurrentDateTime2
```

There are other options as well, depending on the ultimate goal (which is not clear from the simplified example). However, again a `cfquery` will only ever return a single result. If you actually do need multiple resultsets, you must use [`cfstoredproc`](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-tags/tags-r-s/cfstoredproc.html) instead.

Comment: Oh good grief! @leigh Your single comment "That seems unlikely. A cfquery is only capable of returning a single resultset" made me look at the queries again as I _KNEW_ this be true and wouldn't you know it, in a hurried rush, I had a typo. Had I slowed down just a bit, I would have seen my error. The first select statement should have been a simple set statement.

Comment: I'm marking this as correct and updating adding a comment to my post since your post got me to the right answer.

Comment: Heh, hate it when that happens!  (I figured the additional descriptions might help the next guy or someone else not as familiar with the details about the cfquery tag).

Comment: @HPWD - BTW, feel free to post the fixed sql as a separate "answer, if you think that would be helpful to others.